# Releasing funds from SIPP without triggering MPAA

Tags: united-kingdom, pension-sipp

I find the MPAA rules confusing.

I am not employed at the moment and would like to extract about 10K GBP from my SIPP this tax year. Does this trigger MPAA?

Comment: How old are you?